# How can I optimize my code to remove whitespace and special characters?

Tags: java

I want to remove white space and special characters and prepend a `+` to the following input:

```
String numberTo = "+1-     801-351-9512";
```

Expected Output:

```
+18013519502
```

The code I have tried:

```
static String removeWhiteSpaceAndDashFromNumberAndPrependChar(String numberTO) {
  numberTO = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(numberTO);
  numberTO = StringUtils.remove(numberTO, "-");
  numberTO = StringUtils.prependIfMissing(numberTO, "+", "+");

  return numberTO;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your method could do a single pass, and remove all non-numeric characters. You asked about "removing special characters", but your method only removes spaces and dashes.

Comment: I don't have a big issue with your current approach, and I can't think of a much better way to do this.

Comment: Could at least be shortened to 2 method calls with `numberTO=numberTO.replaceAll("\\D","");` and `numberTO=StringUtils.prependIfMissing(numberTO, "+", "+");`

Comment: If your coding attempt is not "broken" and you are wishing to receive a review of your code, then I recommend migrating your question to CodeReview because that's what they do there.  The answers will be deeply considered and usually more educational / comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way I could come up with:

```
String numberTo = "+1- 801-351-9512";
numberTo = "+" + numberTo.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

It removes all non-digit values and then prepends `+` in the same call

Comment: alphanumeric -> digit

Comment: The `+` should only be appended if it is missing

Comment: @Lino since it is being removed anyways, there is actually no need to check

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you're right, `\D` matches every *non-digit*. Learned something new :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.replaceAll` and regex to do this.

```
static String removeWhiteSpaceAndDashFromNumberAndPrependChar(String number) {
    return "+" + number.replaceAll("[+\\-\\s]+", "");
}
```

This looks simple.

Answer (score 2):

The most optimized way I can think of declaring a static final pattern and used in your code

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "+1- 801-351-9512";

    System.out.println("+" + pattern.matcher(value).replaceAll(""));
}
```

Another approach using Guava library

```
value = StringUtils.join("+" + CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom(value));
```

**NOTE:**

You could also use `String`'s `replaceAll` method with a regular expression but it will not be optimized. The `replaceAll` method always build pattern for every call. and if the `replaceAll` method called in a loop then everytime pattern will be built for no reason. It will be better to build the pattern once and used in our code as same as the first approach,

Comment: `Pattern` is the way to go when one has to replace multiple numbers in a loop. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove all non-alphanumeric characters so it handles everything for you:

```
value = "+" + value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Edited my answer as I just realised that '+' would be removed in the regex as well, so you can skip the the check as it will not have a pre-existing '+' after the regex has been applied.

Comment: `\\D` is way shorter and has the same effect

Answer (score -2):

Using regular expressions and replaceAll method you can achieve this.
Try like below

str.replaceAll("[-,' ']","").

Comment: `-` indicates a range, should be escaped. Also the `,` is not needed, and at last `' '` doesn't indicate a whitespace just remove the `'`

Comment: Thank you. Corrected the expression.

str.replaceAll("[\\- ]","");